# Can the Chartkick gem be used to make advanced timeline charts?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, charts, chartkick

I would like to use the [Chartkick](https://github.com/ankane/chartkick) gem, specifically the Timeline chart. However, the gem's docs only show a basic Timeline chart, while Google charts (which the gem uses) offers the advanced Timeline chart seen [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/timeline#an-advanced-example). Can this type of advanced Timeline chart be created with the Chartkick gem (specifically, I need to show multiple time periods on each row).

Thanks!

**Edit: Add Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: which kind timeline?

Comment: @uzaif the 'advanced-timeline' where there are presidents on one row, vice presidents on the next, etc.

Comment: some example please?

Comment: @uzaif Sure, I added a screenshot of what I'm going for. It is taken from the google charts page linked in my original question. I know this is possible with google charts, but I would like to accomplish it in pure Ruby using the Chartkick gem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be possible. The [advanced example](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/timeline#an-advanced-example) uses four DataTable columns: `Position`, `Name`, `Start`, and `End` and it uses the `groupByRowLabel` option to group the presidents by `Position`.

[Chartkick.js](https://github.com/ankane/chartkick.js/blob/102455c16550c6ff11d67ef35cca1d1b98af2e2e/chartkick.js#L742) (which the chartkick gem uses) has only three columns hardcoded for the Timeline chart: `Name`, `Start`, and `End`.